# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf - "dynamic" select based form

Tags: html, spring, forms, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'd like to create a form in which the values of the further select fields change based on what you chose before.

For example, like in the example below. You choose a brand and then the values of model change based on which brand you chose. So for example you pick Samsung in the first select, then in the second one you can choose from Galaxy S2, Galaxy S3 and so on.

```
<form th:action="@{/someAddress}" method="post" th:object="${someObject}">
            <div>
                <select name="brand" >
                    <option th:each="brand : ${brands}" th:value="${brand.id}" th:text="${brand.name}"/>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                <select name="model" >
                    <option th:each="model IN CHOSEN BRAND'S(above) MODELS" th:value="${model.id}" th:text="${model.name}"/>
                </select>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Is is possible to achieve this? How?

Comment: Thymeleaf renders pages server-side. You will need client-side JavaScript to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible in server side as well as client side with ajax.

> DISCLAIMER: I'm not gonna write any source code as I believe explaining you the concept you will be capable of doing it by yourself. Seriously!

**Server side**

1. Populate the **Brands** and keep the **models** empty.
2. When you select the **brand** write the javascript to submit the form to the server which results the **brands** and the **selectedBrand** along with the **models** specific for the **selectedBrand**

> problem with this method is you have to refresh the page each time you change the brand value.

**Client side with ajax**

1. Populate the **Brands** and keep the **models** empty.
2. When you select the **brand** write the javascript to send an ajax request to the server with the **selectedBrand**
3. which in returns with send back a **json** response with possible **models**.
4. Use javascript to populate the model select. :)

> Use jQuery (easier) or AngularJS (high earning curve)

**Websockets**

1. Populate the **Brands** and keep the **models** empty.
2. When you select the **brand** write the javascript to send a call to your websocket node, get the values and populate the select

Comment: I know it's possible in ajax. I wasn't asking about that.

Comment: Then do the first. The server side by refreshing the page. no Ajax. You have to understand the basics. After you render your output from server side you cannot alter it without another render using a new request unless you change the stuff using javascript in client side. :)